# Add custom attributes to Add Product Page without use Attribute Set

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, custom-attributes

I want to add 2 attributes are following to Add Product Page in Magento2 without use Attribute Set.
Thank in advance!

[image]

Comment: Seem that we cannot do that, we need to assign the new attributes to Attribute Set. We can do it via Setup or do it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add Attributes problematically,you can follow below URL for creating custom product attribute.

URL : https://webkul.com/blog/magento2-how-to-create-product-custom-attribute-from-installer-in-custom-module/
Two more URL's as below :

URL :https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-add-product-attribute-programmatically.html

URL :https://www.atwix.com/magento/adding-attribute-programatically-magento2/

Please comment for more help!

Comment: I appreciate your support. Thank you very much. :)